# Boto3 SQS send_message seems to ignore most of QueryUrl url parts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to send a message to a SQS queue from a lambda in a different region. Queue urls do have the region info so I was just trying to do something like:

```
import boto3
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
response = sqs.send_message(
        QueueUrl="https://sqs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ACCOUNT_ID/OtherRegionQueue",
        MessageBody=msg_str
    )
```

My lambda is in "us-east-1" and I've found out that it's trying to access a SQS in this region instead of "us-west-1" as specified in the QueueUrl param, probably because client() get's the region from config if not specified.

After some small testing looks like send_message() completely ignores QueueUrl parts, except from the protocol and the queue name.

I managed to successfully send_message to another queue in the same region as the lambda with an url just like:

```
QueueUrl="https:SameRegionQueue"
```

Is it possible to send messages to queues in other regions without having to create a per-region clients ?

Comment: Can you share your SQS policy.

Comment: At first I was only allowing the sqs region and error was bc it was trying to access the lambda region instead of the one in url. My resurce policy  is : `Resource: "arn:aws:sqs:*"`

Comment: You want to make a single client which works for every region right ?

Comment: Yes, i expected from the docs that send_message would use the full QueryUrl param and not only the queue's name. My workaround for now is adding 'region_name' kwarg to  client extracting the region from the url with a regex...

Comment: Are you using lambda function, If yes, you can create client inside the  lambda handler too, and before that you can extract the region from url and pass it while creating client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to extract region from url,and create the client with region.

```
def region_extract(url):
    text = url.split('.')
    return text[1]

url = "https://sqs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ACCOUNT_ID/OtherRegionQueue"
region = region_extract(url)
print(region)
```